# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException in an implemented node list

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, nodelist

I've been searching through my code for hours now, and just can't figure out where this exception occurs.

The program is based on an implemented node list.

Code: 
Objectlist class:

```
public class Billiste{


// Datafelter
            private Bil forsteBil;

            public Billiste(){
                forsteBil = null;
            }

            public void settInnNyBil(Bil y){
                /*if(ny == null){
                    return;
                }*/
                System.out.println("fjdklsadkjfldsk");
                if(forsteBil == null){
                    forsteBil = y;
                }
                else{
                    Bil løper = forsteBil;
                    while(løper.nesteBil != null){
                        løper = løper.nesteBil;
                    }
                    løper.nesteBil = y;
                }
                System.out.println(y);

            }

            // Metadata om listeobjektene
            public String toString() {
                String resultat = "";
                Bil løper = forsteBil;

                while(løper!=null){
                    resultat += løper.toString() + "\n";
                    løper = løper.nesteBil;
                }
                if(!resultat.equals("")){
                    return resultat;
                }else{
                    return "Ingen biler registrert";
                }
            }
            }// ~Billiste
```

Object class:

```
public class Bil {

//Datafelter
private String kjennetegn;
private String merke;
private String type;
Bil nesteBil;

public Bil(String nyK, String nyM, String nyT){
    System.out.println("Den får tak i stringene k,m og t - de er ikke null");
    kjennetegn = nyK;
    merke = nyM;
    type = nyT;
    nesteBil = null;
    System.out.println("Endelse på funksjonen");
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Bil [kjennetegn=" + kjennetegn + ", merke=" + merke + ", type="
            + type + ", nesteBil=" + nesteBil + "]";
}
}//~Bil
```

This is where the error points:

```
    public void nyBil(){
        Bil ny = new Bil(regnummertekst.getText(), merke.getText(), type.getText());
        bilregister.settInnNyBil(ny);
        output.setText(bilregister.toString());
    }
```

And finally the error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at BilListeGui.nyBil(BilListeGui.java:79)
at BilListeGui.actionPerformed(BilListeGui.java:86)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I would appreciate all the help I can get.

Thanks in advance

Comment: where are you instanciating bilregister and output? I have the strong feeling that the error is in this direction...

Comment: It seems a button in your `BilListeGui` is not initialized. Please post the contents of `BilListeGui` as well.

Comment: HAAH, thank you so much :) You directed me in the right direction! I forgot to instanciate bilregister -_- I had just declared...

Comment: Nice. Please write an answer to your question that shows how you fixed the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, there was no instance of bilregister, thereby giving the error NullPointerException.